# Powershell ISE Window - black square appearing where I drag code, code vanishes

Tags: powershell

This black space appears when I dragged some code to a different spot?  My code disappeared and this showed up?  What's it called and how to I avoid it (and how do I get my code back)?
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dbtx.png)

Comment: Click on the link to see the image

Comment: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What you are seeing is something environmental on your host, not really a PowerShell code or script issue; which is what we are here to assist with. Just use the ISE menu `Tools\options\restore defaults` and try to reset your ISE environment or save your code, close as restart the ISE.